# Scrapy - How to avoid grouping gathered information into one item

Tags: python, html, web, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm having trouble with the data I'm gathering with Scrapy. It appears that when I run this code in the terminal, the information that is gathered is all appended into one item that looks like:

```
{"fax": ["Fax: 617-638-4905", "Fax: 925-969-1795", "Fax: 913-327-1491", "Fax: 507-281-0291", "Fax: 509-547-1265", "Fax: 310-437-0585"], 
"title": ["Challenges in Musculoskeletal Rehabilitation", "17th Annual Spring Conference on Pediatric Emergencies", "19th Annual Association of Professors of Human & Medical Genetics (APHMG) Workshop & Special Interest Groups Meetings", "2013 AMSSM 22nd Annual Meeting", "61st Annual Meeting of Pacific Coast Reproductive Society (PCRS)", "Contraceptive Technology Conference 25th Anniversary", "Mid-America Orthopaedic Association 2013 Meeting", "Pain Management", "Peripheral Vascular Access Ultrasound", "SAGES 2013 / ISLCRS 8th International Congress"],  ... ...
```

... etc.

The issue is that **all of the scraped information for each field ends up in one item.** I need the information to come out as separate items. In other words, I need **each** title to correlate with **one** fax number (if one exists), and **one** location and so on.

I don't want all of the information to appear grouped together because each piece of information gathered has a certain relation to other pieces of info. The way I will eventually want it entered into the database is something like:

"MedEconItem" 1: [title: "insert title 1 here", fax: "insert fax # 1 here", location: "location 1"... ]

"MedEconItem" 2: [title: "title 2", fax: "fax # 2", location: "location 2" ... ]

"MedEconItem" 3: [... and so on

Any thoughts on how to approach this problem? Does anybody know how to separate this information easily? This is my first time working with Scrapy so any advice is welcome. I've been searching everywhere and I can't seem to find an answer.

Here is my code currently:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MedEconItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    date = Field()
    location = Field()
    specialty = Field()
    contact = Field()
    phone = Field()
    fax = Field()
    email = Field()
    url = Field()

class autoupdate(BaseSpider):
   name = "medecon"
   allowed_domains = ["www.doctorsreview.com"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.doctorsreview.com/meetings/search/?region=united-states&destination=all&specialty=all&start=YYYY-MM-DD&end=YYYY-MM-DD",
       ]

   def serialize_field(self, field, name, value):
       if field == '':
           return super(MedEconItem, self).serialize_field(field, name, value)

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//html/body/div[@id="c"]/div[@id="meeting_results"]')
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           item = MedEconItem()
           item['title'] = site.select('//h3/a/text()').extract()
           item['date'] = site.select('//p[@class = "dls"]/span[@class = "date"]/text()').extract()
           item['location'] = site.select('//p[@class = "dls"]/span[@class = "location"]/a/text()').extract()
           item['specialty'] = site.select('//p[@class = "dls"]/span[@class = "specialties"]/text()').extract()
           item['contact'] = site.select('//p[@class = "contact"]/text()').extract()
           item['phone'] = site.select('//p[@class = "phone"]/text()').extract()
           item['fax'] = site.select('//p[@class = "fax"]/text()').extract()
           item['email'] = site.select('//p[@class = "email"]/text()').extract()
           item['url'] = site.select('//p[@class = "website"]/a/@href').extract()
           items.append(item)
       return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code below appears to work but sadly involves some blatant hacks since I am terrible at xpath. Someone better versed in xpath may provide a better solution at a later point.

```
   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//html/body/div[@id="c"]/div[@id="meeting_results"]//a[contains(@href,"meetings")]')
       items = []
       for site in sites[1:-1]:  
           item = MedEconItem()
           item['title'] = site.select('./text()').extract()
           item['date'] = site.select('./following::p[@class = "dls"]/span[@class="date"]/text()').extract()[0]
           item['location'] = site.select('./following::p[@class = "dls"]/span[@class = "location"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
           item['specialty'] = site.select('./following::p[@class = "dls"]/span[@class = "specialties"]/text()').extract()[0]
           item['contact'] = site.select('./following::p[@class = "contact"]/text()').extract()[0]
           item['phone'] = site.select('./following::p[@class = "phone"]/text()').extract()[0]
           item['fax'] = site.select('./following::p[@class = "fax"]/text()').extract()[0]
           item['email'] = site.select('./following::p[@class = "email"]/text()').extract()[0]
           item['url'] = site.select('./following::p[@class = "website"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
           items.append(item)
       return items
```

Comment: I tried this code out, but it's raising a NotImplementedError. It says that it crawled the website, but it then says it has an error at the GET saying **ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www...**. There is no reference to any specific lines in my code.

 Thanks a bunch though! I might add that I am terrible at xpath also.

Comment: That's odd. What version of scrapy are you using?

Comment: I suspect that the NotImplementedError is being thrown by serialize_field since that it is not implemented by spiders but by item exporters. Comment that function out and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: ... (skip some) ...
   'File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 488, in _startRunCallbacks
     self._runCallbacks()
 --- <exception caught here> ---
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 575, in _runCallbacks
     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spider.py", line 57, in parse
     raise NotImplementedError
 exceptions.NotImplementedError: 
'